# How to change the color of the text dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I wanted to change the color of the heading during specific times of the day.(e.g At night blue, in the morning green...)
For this I'm trying to use inline-css(inside js file).

My css file:

```
.heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

My js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const root = document.getElementById("root");

const curretnTime = new Date().getHours();

if (curretnTime < 12 && curretnTime >= 0) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading">Good Morning</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
} else if (curretnTime >= 12 && curretnTime <= 18) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1>Good Afternoon</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1>Good Evening</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
}
```

I know it is pretty easy question to ask, but any answer would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Add style inside your H1 element. <h1 style="color: blue">Good Evening</h1>.            This is called inline style. Alternative define CSS class .headingBlue etc. and use <h1 class="headingBlue">Good Evening</h1>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use inline styles, like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const root = document.getElementById("root");

const curretnTime = new Date().getHours();

let timeOfDay = 'evening';   // not used

let timeOfDayColor = 'blue';
let timeOfDayMessage = 'Good Evening';

if (curretnTime < 12 && curretnTime >= 0) {
   timeOfDay = 'morning';

   timeOfDayColor = 'green';
   timeOfDayMessage = 'Good Morning';

} else if (curretnTime >= 12 && curretnTime <= 18) {
   timeOfDay = 'afternoon';

   timeOfDayColor = 'purple';
   timeOfDayMessage = 'Good Afternoon';
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading" style={{backgroundColor: timeOfDayColor}} >{timeOfDayMessage}</h1>
    </div>,
    root
);
```

The `style={{backgroundColor: timeOfDayColor}}` is your inline style that overrides the CSS style : https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

However, **you should really use components** and not have all the code in the ReactDOM.render method. Maybe try a react tutorial first: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using different classes over inline css.

```css
.heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.heading.morning {
  color: green;
}

.heading.afternoon {
  color: purple;
}

.heading.night {
  color: blue;
}
```

```
if (currentTime < 12 && currentTime >= 0) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading morning">Good Morning</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
} else if (currentTime >= 12 && currentTime <= 18) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading afternoon">Good Afternoon</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading night">Good Evening</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways, one of them is below:

JS file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const root = document.getElementById("root");

const curretnTime = new Date().getHours();
if (curretnTime < 12 && curretnTime >= 0) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div className="morning">
      <h1>Good Morning</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
} else if (curretnTime >= 12 && curretnTime <= 18) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1>Good Afternoon</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div className="evening">
      <h1>Good Evening</h1>
    </div>,
    root
  );
}
```

CSS file

```
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.morning {
  color: green;
}

.evening {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not using inline-css - `To use inline styles, add the style attribute to the relevant element. The style attribute can contain any CSS property.`. But that is just "definition".

Anyway, what are you doing is not correct. You should create a component (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) where you will have logic for the change of color (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do - you can save the color in `state`). Then you can add the `componentDidMount` method and there you can add `setInterval` - so you can basically set "every X hour I will change the color".

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const time = new Date().getHours();
let greeting;
let color = {};

if (time <= 12) {
  greeting = 'Good morning';
  color.color = 'red';
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 18) {
  greeting = 'Good afternoon';
  color.color = 'green';
} else {
  greeting = 'Good night';
  color.color = 'blue';
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1 className="heading" style={color}>
    {greeting}
  </h1>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const currentDate = new Date();
//const hour = 19; // anything b/w 0 - 24 to check
const hour  = currentDate.getHours();

let greeting = "Good Evening";
let colorStyle = { color: "blue" };

if (hour >= 0 && hour <= 12) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
    colorStyle = { color: "red" };
} 
else if (hour >= 12 && hour <= 18) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
    colorStyle = { color: "green" };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>

      <h2 style={colorStyle}>{greeting}</h2>

  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Please try to add few lines to describe your code to let others to know what are doing in the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:-**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const curretnTime = new Date().getHours();

let greetings;
const customStyle = {
  color: ""
  };

 if (curretnTime < 12) {
  greetings = "Good Morning";
  customStyle.color = "red";
 } else if (curretnTime < 18) {
  greetings = "Good Evening";
  customStyle.color = "green";
 } else {
  greetings = "Good Night";
  customStyle.color = "blue";
 }

 ReactDOM.render(<h1 className="heading" style={customStyle} > 
 {greetings}</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//YOu can try this

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const today = new Date();
const hour = today.getHours();

const text = {
  color: "",
  backgroundColor: ""
};

let greet;

if (hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
  greet = "Good morning";
  text.color = "orange";
  text.backgroundColor = "blue";
} else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 16) {
  greet = "Good Afternoon";
  text.color = "blue";
  text.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else if (hour >= 16 && hour < 19) {
  greet = "Good Evening";
  text.color = "white";
  text.backgroundColor = "purple";
} else {
  greet = "Good Night";
  text.color = "grey";
  text.backgroundColor = "pink";
}

ReactDOM.render(<h1 style={text}>{greet}</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This can be improved. The whole block of if and else can be put inside a separate function. And can call it inside of a useEffect, so that  when the component is ready to render, the required data is also ready.